# How to prevent JAWS from reading password when typing any key on keyboard?

Tags: jaws-screen-reader

Jaws is reading passwords.  How can I prevent it from reading the password while I am at the password field? I started typing my password and it announces my password. Also, how can I prevent it from reading it by using Angular? I am using Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Add `role="textbox"` to the password field if you are not creating dots with CSS and JAWS will instead read "bullet bullet bullet". This is more workaround than solution but I found it works best across browsers and JAWS versions.

If you don't target really old JAWS (<13); you can also use `aria-label="text to read"` and that should override JAWS reading actual password entered. I had mixed success with this approach on text-boxes/password-boxes depending on browser and JAWS version used.

Comment: I am using dots  and when I type  any key on Password filed it announce let say my password is "Ques@089" when I type this password in Password field it start announcing the same. I want it not to announce the actual password or if it is announcing it announce as "bullet bullet bullet bullet..." ".........".

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="password">`

This will displays asterisks or bullet points (depending on the browser) in the password field as you type and will prevent the screen reader from announcing the letter you're typing.  But it also means the user must be a touch-typist because they won't hear what they're typing.  The screen reader will just say "star star star" as you type.